# Using jQuery .each() to preset visibility based on status of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, each

In the script below, I'm attempting to evaluate all checkbox items with class "cb-checkURL" and if checked, I want to set the nearest ".wl-options" div to display:block via jQuery show().

However, I'm missing something, the .each is not doing the job. Any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each( ".cb-checkURL", function() {
        if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){
            jQuery(this).parent().next(".wl-options").show();
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery(this).parent().next(".wl-options").hide();
        }
    });

    jQuery(".cb-checkURL").click(
        function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().next(".wl-options").toggle();
        });
})';
```

HTML SOURCE

```
<label class="wl-active">
    <input class="cb-checkURL" type="checkbox" name="wl[item-2][location][is_url]" checked="checked">&nbsp;URL
</label>
<div class="wl-options" style="clear:both;max-width:400px;display:none">
    <div class="cb-urls">
        <label title="Enter one url slug per line" for="wl[item-2][url][urls]"></label>
        <textarea name="wl[item-2][url][urls]" id="wl[item-2][url][urls]"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be much more simple:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var handler = function() {       
        jQuery(this).parent().next(".wl-options").toggle(jQuery(this).is(':checked'));        
    };

    jQuery(".cb-checkURL").click(handler).each(handler);          
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jA4wS/

Answer (score 0):

Your not selecting any element in DOM. 
"The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. ", http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
try:

```
jQuery(".cb-checkURL").each(function( index ) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery.each( ".cb-checkURL", function() {
```

you want

```
$(".cb-checkURL").each(function(index) {
    // do something on each .cb-checkURL
  });
```